# How can I group Pandas Dataframe by score sums <= a max value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns: one of `ID`'s and one of how many `hits` that ID has.  I want to group this data in to groups of `ID`s whose `hits` sum is as close to 10000 as possible.

A simpler type problem is to have a DataFrame with a `coin` column (with values `[penny, nickle, dime, quarter]` and a `cents` column showing total value those coins have in my pocket (not the count of that coin: 1 nickle means 5 `cents`).  I want to group coins into values of as close to $1 (100 cents) as I can, but without going over.  Also, in this problem, we have to use all the cents of a given coin in our grouping (ie I can't just take 25 pennies to sum with the 75 cents worth of quarters to get a perfect dollar).   So, given this DataFrame:

```
     coin           cents
0    penny          32
1    nickle         50
2    dime           80
3    quarter        75
```

...the grouping I'm looking for is:
0 [penny, nickle]
1 [dime]
2 [quarter]

This grouping is the only way to sum values as close to $1 without going over.

Is there a way of achieving this grouping using pandas or numpy functions alone?  Or must I iterate through the dataframe and make my grouping using Python code?

Comment: Use case: ElasticSearch can only return 10k docs in a single query, so if i can first get a list of each `ID` and the number of `docs` each has, then I can create a few ElasticSearch queries (one for each ID group)  to grab all my documents more quickly than 1 search per ID.

Comment: My discrete math is a bit rusty, but it seems like you're describing the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is one of the most common [np complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problems in computer science. Put simply, there's no known solution that doesn't boil down to just brute forcing it and testing every combination.